How to avoid repeated input while using newcommand?
\newcommand\ppp[2]{The width of #1 is \settowidth{\MyLength}{#1} and the text is #2}

Now if #1 is part of #2, are there any ways to avoid repeat input?
For example:
Input \ppp{aaaaa}{bbaaaaacc}
Output The width of aaaaa is 26.34842pt and the text is bbaaaaacc
I don't want to repeat input.
Is it possible to adjust so that something like
\ppp{bb{aaaaa}cc} has the same result?

I'd use something like \newcommand\ppp[2]{The width of #1 is \settowidth{\MyLength}{#1} and the text is #2#1#3} with \ppp{aaaaa}{bb}{cc}.

Sorry,but I don't see the problem (and your definition of \ppp won't show the width of #1). Why not just:
\newcommand\ppp[3]{The width of #2 is \settowidth{\MyLength}{#2}\the\MyLength\ and the text is #1#2#3.}

and
\ppp{bb}{aaaaaa}{cc}

As an alternative you can use \NewDocumentCommand and define #1 and #3 optional:
\NewDocumentCommand{\ppp}{O{}mO{}}{The width of #2 is \settowidth{\MyLength}{#2}\the\MyLength\ and the text is #1#2#3}

Now you can use:
\ppp{aaaaaaa}[cc]
\ppp[bb]{aaaaaaa}
\ppp{aaaaaaa}
\ppp[bb]{aaaaaaa}[cc]

Both suggestions would keep the usual LaTeX syntax instead of come up with a new one.
Here a complete example using the second suggestions:
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\MyLength
\NewDocumentCommand{\ppp}{O{}mO{}}{The width of #2 is \settowidth{\MyLength}{#2}\the\MyLength\ and the text is #1#2#3}

\begin{document}
\ppp{aaaaaaa}[cc]

\ppp[bb]{aaaaaaa}

\ppp{aaaaaaa}

\ppp[bb]{aaaaaaa}[cc]

\end{document}



If you want to use your syntax \ppp{bb{aaaa}cc}, then you can define the macro \ppp in this way:
\def\ppp#1{\pppA#1\end{#1}}
\def\pppA#1#{\pppB}
\def\pppB#1#2\end#3{%
   whole paremater is #3, its internal part is #1.
}

\ppp{bb{aaaa}cc}

prints: whole paremater is bbaaaacc, its internal part is aaaa.

I can see an application for this in hiding part of a word.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l__weixiao_hidden_dim
\seq_new:N \l__weixiao_hidden_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\ppp}{O{/}m}
 {
    \regex_split:nnN {#1} {#2} \l__weixiao_hidden_seq
    \__weixiao_hidden_do:eee
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__weixiao_hidden_seq {1} }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__weixiao_hidden_seq {2} }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__weixiao_hidden_seq {3} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__weixiao_hidden_do:nnn
 {
  \settowidth{\l__weixiao_hidden_dim}{#2}
  #1\makebox[\l__weixiao_hidden_dim]{\hrulefill}#3
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__weixiao_hidden_do:nnn {eee}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ppp{bb/aaaa/cc}

bbaaaacc

\ppp{xyz}

\ppp[\+]{xyz+qq/qq+xyz}

xyzqq/qqxyz

\end{document}

A separator is defined with the optional argument, default a slash. However, the character should be escaped if it has a meaning by itself in regular expressions, such as | as in the example.
There may be tiny differences due to kerning at the head and tail of the hidden part with the letters preceding or following, but I don't think it's an important aspect.

On the other hand, three arguments are much easier to deal with.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ppp}[3]{%
  #1%
  \settowidth{\dimen@}{#2}\makebox[\dimen@]{\hrulefill}%
  #3%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ppp{bb}{aaaa}{cc}

bbaaaacc

\end{document}



In case you wish to avoid delimited macro arguments with delimiters other than {1 and with the TeX engine in use \expanded and \unexpanded are available and you can take for granted that \ppp's argument contains a brace group {1...}2, you can do s.th. like this:
\long\def\firstofone#1{#1}%
\long\def\PassFirstToSecond#1#2{#2{#1}}%

\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00%
\long\def\ppp#1#2{\romannumeral\expanded{\pppAuxA{#1}#2}}%
\long\def\pppAuxA#1#2#{\pppAuxB{#1}{#2}}%
\long\def\pppAuxB#1#2#3{\iffalse{\fi\unexpanded{\expandafter\stopromannumeral#1{#2}{#3}}\expandafter}\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi}%

\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \firstofone{The width of #2 is \settowidth\MyLength{#2}\the\MyLength} and the text is #1#2#3%
}{\long\def\macro#1#2#3}%
\show\macro


\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ppp{\macro}{bb{aaaaa}cc}%
}%

\show\test

\stop

Messages written to console:
$ pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
> \macro=\long macro:
#1#2#3->The width of #2 is \settowidth \MyLength {#2}\the \MyLength  and the te
xt is #1#2#3.
l.14 \show\macro
                
? 
> \test=macro:
->The width of aaaaa is \settowidth \MyLength {aaaaa}\the \MyLength  and the te
xt is bbaaaaacc.
l.23 \show\test
               
? 
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.

